# Why is textbox is always geting focus when I click the blank area of the page?

Tags: uwp, textbox, uwp-xaml

[image]

As the gif shows, My textbox is at the top of the scrollviewer. But when I scroll down, and click the blank area, the textbox always get focused.

It's annoying.

How to remove the textbox's auto focused?

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Padding="5" Style="{StaticResource ScrollViewerAppleStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MinHeight="100" MaxHeight="400"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBox Text="欢迎使用小冰科技最新研发的自然语言处理程序。"  x:Name="textInput" x:Uid="textBox_Input" TabIndex="-1" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" Style="{StaticResource TransparentBackgroundTextBoxStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>

            Other controls.......

        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Have you tried IsTabStop="false" ?

Comment: Yeah, if  IsTabStop="false" , then I can't edit the textbox.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this on my side. Could it be in the ScrollViewerAppleStyle? Could you try removing it now to check if it works without it?

Comment: No,not that reason. You can try add many controls, to more than one page. then at the bottom of the page, click the blank area, the textbox always get focused.

Comment: @Vincent try IsFocusEngagementEnabled="true" on the ScrollViewer.  Also try wrapping the grid in an ItemsControl, which is a focusable container (although so is ScrollViewer).  And yeah you can put stuff in GotFocus and LostFocus events.  There are countless ways to hack your way out of this.

Comment: Ah, seems too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem it had got easily fixed when the `IsTabStop` property of ScrollViewer is set to `True`.

```
<ScrollViewer IsTabStop="True">
    //your code with TextBox in here
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this slightly annoying bug, which when in conjunction with a `ScrollViewer` leads to very undesired behavior.

It seems that when you loose focus of a previously focused control, another control will have to be assigned the focus. 
The `TextBox` is the first control "focus-able" on your page and therefore it will be the one to to be given focus, which leads to the `ScrollViewer`being forced to change its view to the vertical offset where the `TextBox` is defined at.

The easiest possible option would be to handle the `LostFocus` event, and assign the focus to another control which wouldn't cause such a notable issue.

The reason why this behavior happens I guess is to not ruin the experience of keyboard-only users.

Comment: Yeah, Only if a **TextBox** in a **ScrollViewer**, this happens.

Comment: @Vincent Indeed! Can you try to set your Button IsTabStop dependency property to false. This way they won't steal the focus from the TextBox, which should prevent the auto focus which is later given to the textbox, which chains a ScrollViewer ChangeView event.